# Find the values in this polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Could I please have help with this polynomial.

If (2x-3) and (x+2) are factors of 2x$^3$ + a$x^2$ +bx + 30, find the values of a and b.

So x = 3/2 or x = -2

When x = -3/2 = 9/4a + 3/2b + 147/4

When x = -2 = b = -7 + 2a

I got a = 5

But the ANSWER is a = -9 and b = -11

Comment: +3/2, not -3/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the degree of $p(x):=2x^3+ax^2+bx+30$ is three, there must be another degree-one factor, i.e. 
$$
(2x-3)(x+2)(cx+d)=2x^3+ax^2+bx+30
$$

You can see immediately that $c=1$ and $d=-5$ because $2\cdot1\cdot c=2$ and $-3\cdot 2\cdot d=30$. Now you only have to do the multiplication on the left-hand-side and you get the values of $a,b$.

Comment: This is confusing please elaborate further

Comment: There is nothing more I can add. Would you please be so kind to underline exactly your doubts? Do you have any specifical questions? Which points are not clear?

Comment: " (2x−3)(x+2)(cx+d)=2x3+ax2+bx+30

You can see immediately that c=1 and d=−5 because 2⋅1⋅c=2 and −3⋅2⋅d=30. Now you only have to do the multiplication on the left-hand-side and you get the values of a,b. " This entire thing is confusing. How do you see that c =1 ? and d = -5?

Comment: If you do the computations, on the left-hand-side you have the polynomial $2cx^3 + (c+2d)x^2 + (d-6c)x - 6d$. Since this must be equal to your polynomial you get in particular $2c=2$ and $-6d=30$. Once you have the values of $b,c$ you have finished, because $a=c+2d$ and $b=d-6c$.

Comment: I am not understanding this at all.